# Как записать текущую дату в базу данных(по нажатию на ссылку)?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Проблема в следующем: есть ссылка `<a role="button" class="" href="/ru/admin/postedit/647" title="Редактировать"></a>`
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на нее записывалась в базу текущая дата( в TIMESTAMP).
Как решить эту проблему?
ЗЫ: сайт на фреймворке CakePHP.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Вы читали документация к фреймворку? Какую версию вы используете?

Если CakePHP 2, то чтобы добавить запись в бд нужно использовать метод [`save`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) конкретной модели.

Например:

```
$this->ModelName->save($data);
```

Чтобы обновить данные, нужно указать значение для свойства `id` конкретной модели и также использовать метод `save`:

```
$this->ModelName->id = $id;
$this->ModelName->save($data);
```

Также, думаю вам стоит знать про [поля `created` и `modified`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified)

Answer (score 0):

как общепринятый (но уже не рекомендуемый) - ajax, как современный и более универсальный - websocket. даже если передать на сервер только факт нажатия - очень выгодно и просто.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `onclick` атрибут на `<a>` тег.
Напишите функцию, которая будет отправлять на скрипт `id` и по ней обновлять уже дату.

```
<a role="button" class="" href="/ru/admin/postedit/647" onclick="refreshDate(647)" title="Редактировать"></a>
```

**JS**

```
function refreshDate(id){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'updDate.php',
        date : 'id=' + id
    })
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1111', 'news');
    $upd = $mysqli->query("UPDATE news_tbl 
    SET `time`=NOW()
    WHERE `id`='{$_POST['id']}' LIMIT 1")
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @DaVinchi, только не забудьте поменять всё на свои значения